# Avoid multiple inheritance induced ambiguity by using scope resolution

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, diamond-problem

Here is an example of multiple inheritance. I used the scope resolution operator to resolve the ambiguity instead of a virtual class.

```
struct A 
{
    int i;
};

struct B : A
{};

struct C : A
{};

struct D: B, C 
{
    void f()
    {
        B::i = 10;
    }
    void g()
    {
        std::cout << B::i <<std::endl;
    }
};

int main() 
{
    D d1;
    d1.f();
    d1.g();
    return 0;
}
```

Is `B::i` well-formed?

Comment: Or not bother with the multiple inheritance in the first place.

Comment: @Ron - Sometimes, you gotta do what you gotta do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is `B::i` well-formed?

Yes, it is. The most pertinent reference is [[class.qual]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.qual#1):

> If the nested-name-specifier of a qualified-id nominates a class, the
>   name specified after the nested-name-specifier is looked up in the
>   scope of the class, except for the cases listed below. **The name
>   shall represent one or more members of that class or of one of its
>   base classes**.

Which specifies you can name `i` on account of it being a member of `B`'s base. The accessibility is only checked afterwards, and in your case it's public.

[[class.access.base]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.access#base-5)

> ... The access to a member is affected by the class in which the
>   member is named. This naming class is the class in which the member
>   name was looked up and found... A member m is accessible at the point
>   R when named in class N if
>
> - there exists a base class B of N that is accessible at R, and m is accessible at R when named in class B.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. These are extract of the c++ standard grammar rules:

```
id-expression:
  unqualified-id
  qualified-id

postfix-expression:
  [...]
  postfix-expression . template[opt] id-expression
  [...]
```

In [class.mcft.non-static]:

> When an id-expression (8.1) that is not part of a class member access syntax (8.2.5) and not used to form
>   a pointer to member (8.3.1) is used in a member of class X in a context where this can be used (8.1.2), if
>   name lookup (6.4) resolves the name in the id-expression to a non-static non-type member of some class
>   C, and if either the id-expression is potentially evaluated or C is X or a base class of X, the id-expression is
>   transformed into a class member access expression (8.2.5) using (*this) (12.2.2.1) as the postfix-expression
>   to the left of the . operator.